# Comparing 2 tables and updating a column based on results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

TableA

```
Category  Code Sub
           AA   CS
           AB   CD
  TK       AS
```

TableB

```
Category  Code Sub  Found
  D1       AA   CS    0
           AA   CS    0
  D3            CD    0
  TK       AS         0
```

How can I use TableA to update TableB to the following where found will only equal 1 if an entire row is found that matches that in TableA?

```
Category  Code Sub  Found
  D1       AA   CS    0
           AA   CS    1
  D3            CD    0
  TK       AS         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists` :

```
update b
      set b.found = 1
from tableb b
where exists (select 1 
              from tablea a 
              where b.category = a.category and 
                    b.code = a.code and 
                    b.sub = a.sub
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
update b
    set found = 1
    from b join
         a
         on b.category = a.category and b.code = a.code and b.sub = a.sub;
```

This assumes that the blanks are empty strings, rather than `NULL`.

If they are `null`, then performance will likely suffer, but you can do:

```
update b
    set found = 1
    from b join
         a
         on (b.category = a.category or b.category is null and a.category is null) and
            (b.code = a.code or b.code is null and a.code is null) and
            (b.sub = a.sub or b.sub is null and a.sub is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query, that uses `JOIN` to join TableA and TableB and handles null values using `COALESCE` while joining:

```
UPDATE
        tb
SET
        Found = 1
FROM
        TableB tb
    JOIN
        TableA ta
            ON COALESCE(tb.Category, 0) = COALESCE(ta.Category, 0)
               AND COALESCE(tb.Code, 0) = COALESCE(ta.Code, 0)
               AND COALESCE(tb.Sub, 0) = COALESCE(ta.sub, 0);
```